# how to change button text after click in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have designed a button in my nib file. Its initial text is defined as "Not Click" but when program will run and user will click on button it should say "clicked". How will I change text of button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user click on button, you would be receiving the touch event in event method.

You will receive Touch event only if you define action or bind action to that button. so bind this method to your Button touchUpInside event.

First write below code in your .h File.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
```

Then Write below method in .m file.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Clicked";
}
```

Sorry, I edit this answer. Ajay seems at very basic level and I guess he is not aware about bind button action event as well. So I describe that as well.

Comment: Didn't you mean (UIButton *)sender?